# How to get sum of each sector of a column list in a dropdown dashboard based on value in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need to compute sum of Total Revenue in each GICS Sector.

[image]

Seeking help how to get sum of each sector from a dropdown.

[image]

Used SUMIF function without success.

=SUMIF('20_03Project'!J:J,D1,'20_03Project'!E:E)

[image]

After applying SUMIFS, getting a large number of column fields getting populated (actual values are not there, possibly due to error in formula)

Here is the [Excel file link](https://techcosec-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/digitalsplendid_techcosec_onmicrosoft_com/ETZ8_jiQoV9LvZWZd_rFthEBICTpn75ujOUbLPKt9M094A?e=8gmj09).

[image]

Comment: I add a look at your file. The column E of 20_03Project does not contain number or currency. Those values are text. That's why when you sum, the result is 0. You have $ at the beginning and a space at the end of each cell's value. Remove them either manually or with a formula when you do the sum.

Comment: It is working after removing $.

Comment: In order to find sum of total revenue for each year of each GICS sector, here is the formula I tried:

=SUMIFS('20_03Project'!E:E,'20_03Project'!J:J,D1,'20_03Project'!C1,Statistics!B3)

Getting Error in Value due to wrong data type. Is my formula correct and addressing data type will resolve?

https://techcosec-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/digitalsplendid_techcosec_onmicrosoft_com/ETZ8_jiQoV9LvZWZd_rFthEBICTpn75ujOUbLPKt9M094A?e=WgxE3a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must specify the sheet name when the values are not on the sheet where the result must be displayed. Your formula `SUMIF(J:J,D1,E:E)` looks for values on columns J and E which are empty. That is why you get 0 as the values to be summed are not on that sheet.
2. Assumption: You are trying to sum based on GICS Sector, but also the company. If you have many criteria, use `SUMIFS` function.

```
=SUMIFS(20_03Project!E:E,in!J:J,D1,20_03Project!B:B,B1)
```

If you want to sum based only on  GICS Sector, then use the formula:

```
=SUMIF(20_03Project!J:J,Sheet2!D1,20_03Project!E:E)
```

Comment: =SUMIF('20_03Project'!J:J,D1,'20_03Project'!E:E) did not work. Kindly see my updated query.

Comment: @TechcosecLimited Your new formula is incorrect as with SUMIIFS you must first specify the sum range. Column E must be the first argument not J.

Comment: I am trying sum based on GICS Sector alone. For example, when the user selects Consumer Discretion, total revenue in that sector displayed. For this, do I need to use SUMIF or SUMIFS?

Comment: `SUMIF() ` is restricted to a single condition, whereas `SUMIFS() ` can use multiple conditions. Beware, though, the order of arguments differs between the two. In a `SUMIF() ` where the condition is applied to a different range to the summand, the summand is the third argument of the function. With `SUMIFS() ` the summand (range with values that are summed) is always the first argument of the function.

Comment: =SUMIFS('20_03Project'!E:E,'20_03Project'!J:J,Statistics!B16,'20_03Project'!C:C,Statistics!B17)  By applying the formula, could achieve the result.